# Pandas groupby to create additional columns from one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that contains a date column and a discount value column, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-06','2023-09-07', '2023-09-08', '2023-09-09', '2023-09-10'],
        'discount': [30, 25, 0, 10, 15, 15,0,25,30,0]})

df
```

[image]

I need to add additional columns that contain the values that precede a zero, where the number of additional columns is determined by the number of 0 delimiters, such that the resultant df looks like this...

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-06','2023-09-07', '2023-09-08', '2023-09-09', '2023-09-10'],
        'discount': [30, 25, 0, 10, 15, 15,0,25,30,0],
        'split1': [30,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'split2': [0,0,0,10,15,15,0,0,0,0],
        'split3': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,30,0]})

df2
```

[image]

So far my attempts have yielded the following;

```
for date, group in df.groupby('date'):
    num_splits = len(group)
    splits = group['discount'].tolist()

    for i in range(num_splits):
        df.loc[group.index[i], f'split{i+1}'] = splits[i]

df
```

[image]

Note - there may be multiple, sequential zeros after a non-zero value in the 'discount' column, so the first non-zero value should be used to define the group.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: what does mean "*all the values that precede every zero*" ?

Comment: This is admittedly confusing, I will edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
m = df['discount'].eq(0)

out = df.join(df[~m]
   .assign(col=m.cumsum().add(1))
   .pivot(columns='col', values='discount')
   .add_prefix('split')
 )
```

Output:

```
         date  discount  split1  split2  split3
0  2023-09-01        30    30.0     NaN     NaN
1  2023-09-02        25    25.0     NaN     NaN
2  2023-09-03         0     NaN     NaN     NaN
3  2023-09-04        10     NaN    10.0     NaN
4  2023-09-05        15     NaN    15.0     NaN
5  2023-09-06        15     NaN    15.0     NaN
6  2023-09-07         0     NaN     NaN     NaN
7  2023-09-08        25     NaN     NaN    25.0
8  2023-09-09        30     NaN     NaN    30.0
9  2023-09-10         0     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Intermediates:
`m` identifies the zeros, `~m` the non-zeros to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) forms the groups that will be used as columns.

```
         date  discount      m     ~m  col
0  2023-09-01        30  False   True    1
1  2023-09-02        25  False   True    1
2  2023-09-03         0   True  False    2
3  2023-09-04        10  False   True    2
4  2023-09-05        15  False   True    2
5  2023-09-06        15  False   True    2
6  2023-09-07         0   True  False    3
7  2023-09-08        25  False   True    3
8  2023-09-09        30  False   True    3
9  2023-09-10         0   True  False    4
```

Comment: Thanks mozway. Could you please explain this approach?

Comment: Sure I added the intermediates before the `pivot`. Let me know if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use :

```
TARGET = "discount"

block = df[TARGET].eq(0).shift(fill_value=True).cumsum()

out = (
    df.assign(**{f"split{idx}": g
                 for idx, g in df.groupby(block)[TARGET]})
        .fillna(0)#.with optional astype() ?
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         date  discount  split1  split2  split3
0  2023-09-01        30   30.00    0.00    0.00
1  2023-09-02        25   25.00    0.00    0.00
2  2023-09-03         0    0.00    0.00    0.00
3  2023-09-04        10    0.00   10.00    0.00
4  2023-09-05        15    0.00   15.00    0.00
5  2023-09-06        15    0.00   15.00    0.00
6  2023-09-07         0    0.00    0.00    0.00
7  2023-09-08        25    0.00    0.00   25.00
8  2023-09-09        30    0.00    0.00   30.00
9  2023-09-10         0    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: Looks like what I'm trying to achieve. Will test.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04',
                           '2023-09-05', '2023-09-06', '2023-09-07', '2023-09-08', '2023-09-09', '2023-09-10'],
                   'discount': [30, 25, 0, 10, 15, 15, 0, 25, 30, 0]})

def create_split_columns_efficiently(df):
    target_col = "discount"
    groups = df[target_col].eq(0).shift(fill_value=True).cumsum()
    #Create split columns, ensuring zeros trigger new splits and handling consecutive zeros:
    max_split = groups.max()
    #print(max_split) #3
    for i in range(1, max_split + 1):
        # Initial assignment
        df[f'split{i}'] = np.where(groups == i, df['discount'], np.nan)  
        #print(df[f'split{i}'])
        # Correctly handle zeros within splits:
        # Set zeros and NaNs to NaN
        df.loc[df[f'split{i}'].eq(0) | df[f'split{i}'].isna(), f'split{i}'] = np.nan 
        # Forward-fill NaNs        
        df.loc[df[f'split{i}'].isna(), f'split{i}'].ffill(inplace=True)  
    
    return df

df_with_split_cols = create_split_columns_efficiently(df)
print(df_with_split_cols)
"""        date  discount  split1  split2  split3
0  2023-09-01        30    30.0     NaN     NaN
1  2023-09-02        25    25.0     NaN     NaN
2  2023-09-03         0     NaN     NaN     NaN
3  2023-09-04        10     NaN    10.0     NaN
4  2023-09-05        15     NaN    15.0     NaN
5  2023-09-06        15     NaN    15.0     NaN
6  2023-09-07         0     NaN     NaN     NaN
7  2023-09-08        25     NaN     NaN    25.0
8  2023-09-09        30     NaN     NaN    30.0
9  2023-09-10         0     NaN     NaN     NaN"""
Intermediates(for analysis):

print(df[f'split{i}'])
0    30.0
1    25.0
2     0.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
Name: split1, dtype: float64
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    10.0
4    15.0
5    15.0
6     0.0
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
Name: split2, dtype: float64
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7    25.0
8    30.0
9     0.0
Name: split3, dtype: float64
```

Explanations :

df[f'split{i}'] = np.where(groups == i, df['discount'], np.nan):

1.Assigns non-zero values from the 'discount' column to the corresponding split column
based on the group label in groups.

2.Fills remaining values with NaN.

df.loc[df[f'split{i}'].eq(0) | df[f'split{i}'].isna(), f'split{i}'] = np.nan:

1.Replaces both zero values and existing NaNs with NaN within each split column.

df.loc[df[f'split{i}'].isna(), f'split{i}'].ffill(inplace=True):

1.Forward-fills NaNs within each split column to propagate non-zero values.